# NotAllowedError : The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, js, user-agent

Hello,

I develop a LWC in a comunity which calls a VF page inside an iFramce to read a QR code (not directly in the LWC because of the DOM).

This is the JS library I use to scan the QR code: https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode

When I call the VF page from the Salesforce, everything works well.

But when I call the VF page from the LWC in the community, everything is fine until I click on a button to run the camera, at this time I get the error message:

> NotAllowedError : The request is not allowed by the user agent or the
> platform in the current context.

I disable the locker service in the community and I added theVF domain as a trusted site.

What can I do to allow to the camera to be loaded?

Is the problem in Salesforce or in the browser?
For me, the user agent is the browser?

Thanks

Comment: One Google result: https://github.com/peer-calls/peer-calls/issues/78 suggesting HTTPS must be used to fix this.

Comment: It is already in HTTPS.